# Clear git repository on Bitbucket?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'm just getting started with git, and started messing about with Bitbucket.  However, I now want to use the repository I created, but without its initial history.

Is there any way I can clear out or purge my repository so that I can start from scratch?

I'm not too bothered about any of the content, so can I just delete the repository, then create a new one with the same name?

Answer (score 157, accepted):

No need to delete it.

From your new local repo create directory or remote simple the .git, if you want upload (without history) an existing repo:

```
 rm -rf .git
```

Recreate the repos from the current content only

```
 git init
 git add .
 git commit -m "Initial commit"
```

Then simply push to the github remote repos ensuring you overwrite history:

```
 git push --force -u origin master
```

That will replace the history of your BitBucket master branch by the new one you have done locally.

Now, if you had pushed other branches before, you might want to [delete them](http://gitready.com/beginner/2009/02/02/push-and-delete-branches.html).

```
git push origin :oldBranch
```

Comment: Great, thanks!  Is there any way to remove the stripping from the recent activity log?

Comment: @MatthewCoster good question. I am not aware of a way to modify that list of activities recorded on the BitBucket side. (a bit like silently deleting a BitBucket repo: https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issue/4271/make-it-possible-to-silently-delete-a). That might be an issue or request for enhancement to add to https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues?status=new&status=open

Comment: this is not an answer. He asked how to clean (empty) repo, not how to replace content of remote repo with local changes

Comment: @qkx I accepted this answer 7 years ago because it did in fact answer my question. My stated intent was to start a new project in the repo, not leave an empty one. This achieves the former without the latter being necessary - an elegant avoidance of the XY problem.

Comment: I updated the answer to show little bit more the possibilites, since I wasn't found all I want to know here.

Comment: @ChristianMüller Yes, thank you for your contribution. Much appreciated. I was the one who approved that edit.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed it works, but for the `push` command you will need to provide again the full path to the repo, since the local repo was reinitialized. So `origin` will need to be replaced with something like this: `https://minime@bitbucket.org/banana/test.git`

The command should look like this:

```
git push --force -u https://minime@bitbucket.org/banana/test.git master
```