# Clear Git repository

Tags: git, tfs, bitbucket, git-tfs

I've to transfert a TFS server to a GIT(Bitbucket) server.

We are currently using `git-tfs` to do it, but we are doing some tests before migrating(like configuring jenkins, checkin that everything is correctly transfered).

The issue is that now it seems I cannot run the `git push` command because I've the repository that is already filled with a lot of stuff from the previous run.

Is there a way to "reset" the repository(like if I've never done any commit) ? Without deleting it?

I've found this: [Clear git repository on Bitbucket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13669410/clear-git-repository-on-bitbucket) but the issue is that I'm committing 6 years of work, with more than 60 branches, so I cannot just clean them one by one.

I also cannot just delete the repository, we have already configured a lot of things(hooks, connections to jenkins, ...).

Comment: *... with more than 60 branches, so I cannot just clean them one by one.* What's the problem with scripting it?

Comment: @Leon I'm open to suggestion, but maybe a previous import didn't work properly or maybe it leaves some things that are not clear(not garbage collected) ?

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on the TFS version/bitbucket. You could just delete all the branches and tags and reset Master to the very first commit to get a clean slate. But depending on your TFS server version this may actually not cause the "garbage" to be collected. I;m not sure about the garbage collection policies on BitBucket.

Git garbage collection was introduced in TFS 2015 update 3 and older versions won't actually clean up anything on the server, even if you've deleted all references to it.

You could easily script the cleanup process. use `git fetch --all` to make sure your local repo has all branch information, then use `git branch --list -r` to list all remote branches. With that you can easily script deleting these branches and pushing their deletion to the server.

[Then use `git update-ref refs/heads/master a12d48e2` (insert your own commitish) to reset the master.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624881/how-can-i-uncommit-the-last-commit-in-a-git-bare-repository)

Then `git push --force --all` to send everything back to the server.

Comment: Hi, not sure why TFS version is important, but currently it's the TFS 2015.
The issue I've with doing a `git --fetch --all`: It will change the git repository I just finished to generate after 8 longs hours, no? How to remove only the remote branch and not the local one?