# Does deleting a repository from a project in TFS 2017 save database space?

Tags: git, tfs

I have a multi-project repository in TFS 2017.  I used git clone --mirror MyRepo to store it off on a file server.  When I delete the repo in TFS

1. Will the deletion reduce the database size for that collection in TFS?
2. Will I need to run the stored procedure DeleteUnusedContent first?
3. I'm guessing deleting the repository will not have an impact on WorkItems at all.?.?

Answer (score 0):

In TFS, the Git repository is stored in the SQL database together with all the other data. Delete a git repo in a team project won't impact on workitems, as workitems are in a team project level, not in a git repo level.

You could script the cleanup process by referring to [Clear Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41564981/clear-git-repository), and use `git fetch --all` to make sure your local repo has all branch information, then use `git branch --list -r` to list all remote branches. With that you can easily script deleting these branches and pushing their deletion to the server.

[Then use `git update-ref refs/heads/master a12d48e2` (insert your own commitish) to reset the master.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624881/how-can-i-uncommit-the-last-commit-in-a-git-bare-repository)

Then `git push --force --all` to send everything back to the server.

Comment: Dong I already mirrored the Repo.  Will deleting it through the TFS Web UI reduce the size of the database?  

I'm guessing deleting the repo via the UI and running a shrinking operation on the database will save me some much needed room.  Do you agree?

Comment: From my test, it won't free the space immediately after you deleting the repo. You could check the solution from this case: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/118099/reduce-tfs-database-size-after-deleting-almost-all.html