# "Repository is in read only mode" error while clearing bitbucker repository via "git push --force -u origin master"

Tags: git

I want to reduce my repository's size, so I'm using

```
git push --force -u origin master
```

as told in 
[Clear git repository on Bitbucket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13669410/clear-git-repository-on-bitbucket)

but getting an error:

```
remote: repository is in read-only mode (over 2 GB size limit).
```

Please point me, what I'm doing wrong. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you committed large files such as audio samples, videos, datasets, or graphics?

Comment: yes, i committed lots of pdfs

Comment: [That’s the issue then.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772048/when-should-pdf-files-be-tracked-in-a-git-repository-and-when-not) - [Have a look at git lfs](https://git-lfs.github.com/)

Comment: I didn't use git lfs while working in this repo. Will git lfs help anyway?

Comment: I don’t actually know. I’ve never used it myself.